# Unions of any basis of topology are in the topology?

Tags: general-topology

I just learned the what basis of topologies are so just a question. If every element of the topology are unions of basis elements, is the converse true? Finite or infinite union of any basis elements are elements of the topology.

Comment: Basis elements are open by definition, and any union of open sets is also open.

Comment: oh right! of course!

Comment: If $b$ is a member of the base (basis) then $\{b\}$ is a  subset of the base, so $b=\cup \{b\}$ belongs to the topology. Using a base can simplify things. E.g. given $f:X\to Y,$ if you have a base $B$ for $X$ such the restriction $f|_b$ of $f$ to $b$ is continuous for each $b\in B$ then you know $f$ is continuous.